# Why is the Android viewModels() extension function available in the fragment-ktx instead of viewmodel-ktx library?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, android-viewmodel

When I use `viewModels()` as below

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val viewModel: MainViewModel by viewModels()

    // ... more codes
}
```

Why is it available in

```
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.0'
```

Instead, when I include things like below, it is not available in them?

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
```

I thought it supposed to be in the `viewmodel-ktx` library instead of `fragment-ktx` library

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/package-summary#viewmodels), the `by viewModels()` extension is an extension on the `Fragment` class and therefore, must belong in the `fragment-ktx` artifact - the `lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx` and `lifecycle-runtime-ktx` do not have any dependency on fragments and the `lifecycle-extensions` artifact is completely deprecated and should not be used at all as per the [Lifecycle 2.2.0 release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#2.2.0).

Comment: Even if I'm using just activity alone, and not fragment, do I also need to include `fragment-ktx` to use the `viewModels()` ?

Comment: Ah, you're talking about the `by ViewModels()` [extension on `ComponentActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/activity/package-summary#(androidx.activity.ComponentActivity).viewModels(kotlin.Function0)). That's in the `activity-ktx` artifact and has nothing to do with fragments. The only relation there is that `fragment-ktx` has a dependency on `activity-ktx`.

Comment: Nice, that explains everything. I was confused why I need to add fragment-kts, and this is now all cleared. Thanks Ian!